# get variable value

Tags: php, variables, class

```
<?php
class obj {
    var $primary_key;

    function obj($key = null){
        if(isset($key)){
            $this->primary_key = $key;
        }
        echo "primary_key: ".$this->primary_key."<br/>";

        $this->obj_id = 14;


        echo "obj_id: ".$this->obj_id."<br/>";

        $key  = $this->primary_key;

        echo "obj_id from primary_key string: ".$this->$key."<br/>";
    }
}
?>
```

Is there a way to get `$this->primary_key` value?
Like `$this->$this->primary_key`?

---

```
<?php
class obj {
    var $primary_key;

    function obj($key = null){
        if(isset($key)){
            $this->primary_key = $key;
        }
        echo "primary_key: ".$this->primary_key."<br/>";

        $this->obj_id = 14;


        echo "obj_id: ".$this->obj_id."<br/>";

        $key  = $this->primary_key;

        echo "obj_id from primary_key string: ".$this->$key."<br/>";
    }
}
?>

$aaa = new obj("obj_id");
```

i want to get $this->obj_id value, but i dont whant to use variable $key.
This line $this->obj_id = 14; will be dynamic and i would't be able to know, 
if $this->obj_id will be named obj_id or something else like $this->banana, it would be desided by new obj("banana")

Comment: it's good if you indicate the language

Comment: Would you care to specify which language this is, and anything else like which OS and/or implementation that might help?

Comment: I tagged this as PHP (the original tags were not relevant) before the comments due to context clues, but I'm obviously not positive, and the question is quite unclear to me.

Comment: Even after reading it twice, I do not understand this question.

Comment: I have to say, unlike many others I don't dislike PHP, as it is very possible to write good code with it. But seeing things like this make me want to cry. I somehow feel sorry for the language itself.

Comment: why you a writing if you dont know what to the answer?

Comment: @Tomas:  In an effort to prompt you to provide information that might help us help you.

Answer (score 1):

Well in order for that function to even be of any use, you would need to create a new class and set it to a variable, such as this:

```
$myclass = new obj(1);
```

Although that form of a constructor is only supported for backward compatibility (deprecated, you're really supposed to use [`__construct`](https://www.php.net/__construct) now), it should still run and set all your variables, which can be retrieved in the following way:

```
echo $myclass->primary_key; // the primary_key value
echo $myclass->obj_id; // the obj_id value
```

Edit: Also this line needs to be corrected to change the '$key' to 'primary_key' near the end. Putting '$key' there will not return anything because it would be sending '$this->1' which does not exist.

```
echo "obj_id from primary_key string: ".$this->primary_key."<br/>";
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$obj_a = new obj(5);
echo $obj_a->primary_key;       // prints '5'
```

Answer (score 0):

In your last line:

```
echo "obj_id from primary_key string: ".$key."<br/>";
```

or:

```
echo "obj_id from primary_key string: ".$this->$primary_key."<br/>";
```

Seriously, I still don't understand the utility of this code...